# Text bold in IE 9,8,7 by default

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

In opera, chrome, safari, firefox my website letters are as supposed to be, sometimes bold when I asked them to and sometimes normal. However, in IE 9,8,7 they are always bold no matter what. Even when I say `font-weight:normal;` or `font-style:normal;` they stay bold :|
Anyone had this problem and knows how to solve it?

For example I have p:

HTML

```
<p id="copyright">© 2013. Company Name. All rights reserved.</p>
```

CSS

```
#copyright {
float:right;
margin-right:5px;
margin-top:42px;
color:#7d7d7d;
font-family:Helvetica;
font-style:normal;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: cleartype. try a different font

Comment: thanks, it works with different font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helvetica isn't a standard font on Windows. Try changing:

```
font-family:Helvetica;
```

to

```
font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

If that's no good, try flipping the order of Arial and Helvetica – it may be that your Windows box has a bad copy of Helvetica installed, and that the ClearType settings in those browsers are making it look wider than it should be.

Comment: thanks, it works with different font. Will accept when allowed, and thats 10 mins :)

Answer (score 4):

That's because of Microsoft's ClearType

Sadly, many fonts looks nearly the same when switching from "normal" to "bold" :(

You should try with a different font (verdana has for example a stronger difference between normal and bold)

Also, you could try to use a .svg web font, which will not be affected by cleartype

HTH